# Give column names to a pandas dataframe created with np.tile

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am building a data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
uniq = df["mycol"].unique()
s = pd.DataFrame(np.tile({'aaa', "bbb",'ccc', "ddd",'eee', "fff",'ggg',"hhh"}, len(uniq)))
```

How can I give a name to the unique column of s?
It name is 0 now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you realise that you are trying to `tile` a set... This will create a column of sets, which I'm sure is not what you want.

Try initialising it as a list:

```
data = ['aaa', "bbb",'ccc', "ddd",'eee', "fff",'ggg',"hhh"]
```

Now, you can use the `pd.DataFrame` constructor.

```
col_name = 'Column1' # replace with any other name
df = pd.DataFrame({col_name :  np.tile(data, len(uniq)) })
df.head(10)

  Column1
0     aaa
1     bbb
2     ccc
3     ddd
4     eee
5     fff
6     ggg
7     hhh
8     aaa
9     bbb
```